Why does Solana Explorer show "Token names and logos are not unique" for my token?
I have a new token built in dexlab. But when I search in Explorer, it displays the below message. I researched some days ago, but I cannot find any way to fix it.

Warning! Token names and logos are not unique. This token may have spoofed its name and logo to look like another token. Verify the token's mint address to ensure it is correct.


Understanding the warning
The warning:

Warning! Token names and logos are not unique. This token may have spoofed its name and logo to look like another token. Verify the token's mint address to ensure it is correct.

Is accurate. Anyone can make a new token on mainnet, set the symbol to be USDC and the logo to be the USDC logo, and make a fake USDC. What they can't do is fake the token's mint address to match what the USDC website says.
Do I, the maker of a token, need to verify the token I made?
The message is mainly for potential users of the token. Eg, someone could make a fake USDC token and ask you to swap it for your real SOL. So users should check the mint address is the one published at a reputable source (eg for USDC, https://www.circle.com/en/multi-chain-usdc/solana)
To make the message go away and become a 'well known' token
Some community groups have lists of 'well known' tokens. This may be based on market cap, team reputation, or other factors.

Solana Explorer uses Solflare's Unified Token List API

solana.fm uses Jupiter's Universal Token List API.


Yes these projects have annoyingly similar names, one is 'Unified' the other is 'Universal'.
