Token icon not shown on phantom
the icon of the token have disappeard on phantom wallet
Ca: Ax5MkegH96hMUTLrgUpgeHE43ShDTvAYciiYi65ukRp6
Also id like to know how can i verify token and social networks

Hrm, it looks good on Explorer: https://explorer.solana.com/address/Ax5MkegH96hMUTLrgUpgeHE43ShDTvAYciiYi65ukRp6. If I were you, I'd edit my question title to be "Icon shows on Explorer but not Phantom".

Regarding verifying tokens, that's a separate question. See https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/13429/why-does-solana-explorer-show-token-names-and-logos-are-not-unique-for-my-toke/15879#15879 for the answer.
